# Document or blog for :In app purchase and Monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, monodevelop

I was looking for how to create the Dev Part of In app purchase :
For the configuration of itunes it is ok.
But did not find any ressources about doing the dev part in MonoTouch.
Any ideas please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some source code available for this on github:

- https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp
- https://github.com/Clancey/ClanceyLib/blob/master/ClanceysLib/AppStore/InAppPurchaseManager.cs