# Does MonoTouch support in-app purchases or payments?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am not seeing much discussion about this ability.  Does it exist?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514531/document-or-blog-for-in-app-purchase-and-monotouch

Answer (score 4):

Yes, MonoTouch supports Apple's StoreKit framework. It actually supports virtually anything that is available to iOS developers via Obj-C:

http://api.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=N%3aMonoTouch.StoreKit